# Codeigniter is inserting spaces automatically

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter in a query on postgresql, it automatically adding a spacebar on the query for no reason

This is the query:

```
if ($_respuesta) {
$this->db->where("regexp_replace(consulta_respuestas.respuesta,'<[^>]*>', '', 'g') LIKE '%".$_respuesta."%'");
}
```

the problem is when i check the output it adds a space in here:

```
' < [^>]*>'
```

Between the apostrophe and the less than symbol, that provokes the query doesn´t work as supposed.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want remove all space. I recommend you should use this commands: $output = stripslashes($output); $output = str_replace(' ', '', $output);

Comment: try the following `$this->db->where("regexp_replace(consulta_respuestas.respuesta,'<[^>]*>', '', 'g') LIKE '%".$_respuesta."%'", NULL, false);`

Comment: Bro, why don't you make you whole pure sql `$query` then put it once in your `$this->db->query($query);` .. always do that when you use complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$reg_val = "<[^>]*>";

if ($_respuesta) {
  $this->db->where("regexp_replace(consulta_respuestas.respuesta, $reg_val, '', 'g') LIKE '%".$_respuesta."%'");
}
```